# Proof of one of the transpose matrix theorms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given an $m\times n$-matrix $A$ and an $n\times p$-matrix $B$. Prove that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$.

I cannot find any proof of it. Could someone explain it please?

I tried and ended up with $A_{ji}B_{ji}=B_{ji}A_{ji}$.